# How does MySQL or PostgreSQL deal with multi-column indexes in ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, index

I'm creating indexes for my models right now and I want to know how MySQL and PostgreSQL deal with an index with more than 1 column like:

```
add_index :users, [:username, :created_at]
```

That should utilize the index when I do a query like (I think):

```
User.where("username = ? and created_at > ?", 'jim', DateTime.now.yesterday)
```

But will it also utilize the index if I only use the username in a query?

```
User.where("username = ?", 'jim')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PostgreSQL at least, multi-column indexes are usable for single-column searches on the left column, but *not* for single-column searches on the right column.

So: an index on `(a,b,c)` can be used for searches on `a`, `a,b` and `a,b,c` but not for searches on `b,c` or `c`.

If search patterns make individually usable indexes on all columns necessary and if the column values are small, people often create indexes `a,b,c`, `b,c` and `c`.

An alternative can be individual indexes on `a`, `b`, and `c`. PostgreSQL can use a *bitmap index scan* in many circumstances to *combine* the indexes, so a search with conditions on `b` and `c` will use *both* the indexes on `b` and `c`.

Rather than guess, the best thing to do is use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` or the `auto_explain` module to examine the query plans and run-time stats from your queries, so you can see what's actually happening.